# SQL 2012 - Common Table Expression - Hierarchy - List All Children Before Parents

Tags: sql, sql-server, hierarchy, common-table-expression, sql-server-2012

I have a problem that I'm trying to solve that I think is different from other SQL adjacency list hierarchy problems I've researched here.  I’m trying to sort the data such that all children are listed before any of their parents.  I already have CTE’s that return all the children of a given ParentID and all the parents of a given ChildID, but those don't fit my current need.

I have two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ItemMaster](
[ItemID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[Name] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[References](
[RefID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[ParentID] [int] NOT NULL,
[ChildID] [int] NOT NULL,
```

Foreign key relationships exist between ItemMaster.ItemID to References.ParentID and References.ChildID

Here's some example data from my tables...

ItemID, Name

- 1, A1
- 2, A2
- 3, A3
- 4, P1
- 5, P2
- 6, P3
- 7, P4
- 8, TOP

RefID, ParentID, ChildID

- 1,1,5
- 2,2,5
- 3,2,6
- 4,3,2
- 5,7,3
- 6,8,4
- 7,8,1
- 8,8,2
- 9,8,3
- 10,8,7

The output I want would list each ItemID and Name with the children listed before any parents.  Like this...

ItemID, Name

- 4, P1
- 5, P2
- 6, P3
- 1, A1
- 2, A2
- 3, A3
- 7, P4
- 8, Top

Notes:

- Any ItemID can have 0, 1 or > 1 parents.

  - Those that don't have any parents would be listed at the top of the output.
- I don't have NULL values for the "top most parents" in the reference table.

I hope I've given enough detail and explained myself well enough to get some feedback.  Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to SO.  It's appreciated that you demonstrate how you tried to solve the issue, otherwise it looks like you just want us to code it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the way to achieve this is using a recursive operation and assigning a weight to each node, based on the weight of all its children.

For example any leaf in this tree will have a weight of zero since it doesn't have any children. Its immediate parent will be 1, and the parent's parent 2 and so on. Sorting on the weight should return the result set you need. Here is the recursive function I used to test my theory:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetItemWeight](@ItemID int)
RETURNS int
BEGIN

DECLARE @Weight int;

SELECT
  @Weight = COUNT(ParentID) 
FROM
  [References]
WHERE
  ChildID = @ItemID;

SELECT
  @Weight = ISNULL(@Weight, 0) + SUM(dbo.GetItemWeight(ChildID))
FROM
  [References]
WHERE
  ParentID = @ItemID;

RETURN ISNULL(@Weight, 0);
END
```

This returns the result set you posted:

```
SELECT ItemID, Name FROM ItemMaster ORDER BY dbo.GetItemWeight(ItemID);
```

Best of luck :)

Comment: Just a follow up.  The above works perfectly for my test dataset, but when run it across my "real" data I'm getting a "Maximum stored procedure, function, trigger or view nesting level exceeded (limit 32)." error.

I'm looking into alternate techniques, but do you happen to know off hand how I might take what you specified and modify\improve on it so that the error can be avoided.

Thanks again!

Comment: Sorry...I'm far from a SQL expert (thus why I'm here), but one alternative I'm considering using a CTE rather than a Function and using OPTION (MAXRECURSION XXXX) where XXXX = a high enough number to get the needed result.  Not sure this will work though??  For this project the best\fastest code isn't high priority since the DB will be throw away after I get the reports I need from it.

Comment: Did some more digging into my problem and I found some circular references in my "References" table.  That would definitely explain why it’s hitting the limit.  I need to get this figured out before proceeding.  Dang it...